# Sorting a dollar amount into 20/10/5/1's using arithmetic operators only (no loops)

Tags: c

I need to write a program that lets the user input a dollar amount, and the program will sort out that dollar amount into 20's, 10's, 5's and 1's. For example, if the user puts in $93, the program will sort out 4 20's, 0 10's, 0 5's and 3 1's, all without using loops, arrays, or if statements.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    //Declarations
    int doll_amt;
    int twentys;
    int tens;
    int fives;
    int ones;

    //Data/Input

    //Output
    printf("Enter a dollar amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &doll_amt);
    printf("Your dollar amount is: %d\n", doll_amt);

    //Processing/Calculations
    twentys = doll_amt / 20;
    tens = (doll_amt / 20) % 10;
    fives = (doll_amt /20) % 5;
    ones = (doll_amt / 20) % 1;

    printf("$20 bills: %d\n", twentys);
    printf("$10 bills: %d\n", tens);
    printf("$5 bills: %d\n", fives);
    printf("$1 bills: %d\n", ones);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically just asking for the input, and dividing the doll_amt by 20 works fine. It's finding the remaining 10's, 5's and 1's that I am having trouble with. Thank you!

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: Reduce the `doll_amt` amount after each change calculation (no loops). Like `doll_amt -= twentys * 20;` Or you can explore modulus calculations with `%` like `doll_amt %= 20;`.

Comment: You mostly swapped `%` and `/` and you use the `20` too often. Try playing with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's finding the remaining 10's, 5's and 1's that I am having trouble with.

Reduce `doll_amt` after each step.  No requirement that denominations are multiples as long as smallest is 1.

```
//twentys = doll_amt / 20;
//tens = (doll_amt / 20) % 10;
//fives = (doll_amt /20) % 5;
//ones = (doll_amt / 20) % 1;  // n%1 always results in 0

twentys = doll_amt / 20;
doll_amt %= 20; 
tens = doll_amt / 10;
doll_amt %= 10; 
fives = doll_amt / 5;
doll_amt %= 5; 
ones = doll_amt;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some swaps of operators here, you confused `%` and `/` for most of the time.
Also you use the `20` too often, you need to focus more and more on the smaller bill values.

```
//Processing/Calculations
twentys =(doll_amt / 20) ; /* fine */
tens =   (doll_amt % 20) / 10; /* divide what is left after twenties    by 10 */
fives =  (doll_amt % 10) /  5; /* divide what is left after 20s and 10s by  5 */
ones =   (doll_amt %  5);      /*        what is left after 20s, 10s, and 5s  */
```

Note that the code would be more complex if bill values would not always be multiples of all lower values.